# change the page format

Tags: graphics, paper-size

[image]

I have this picture which contains so many details. By using A4 Format
it no possible to see all those details. I'd like to chang the format to A3 or A2 only for this page to make this picture visible. Please any one  have an idea how to do it.

Comment: Is the image you're including accompanied by a `\caption` and/or need referencing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if `newgeometry` from the package `newgeometry` can help you.

Comment: Also, do you need the text to flow naturally from page X-1 to X+1 where page X is your A3 image/page? Or, could there be a hard break followed by some blank content on page X-1, with page X+1 starting again at the top?

Comment: How are you going to print an A3 or A2 page in the middle of an A4 document (assuming you want a hard copy at some point)? I would suggest an A4 document plus a one page A3/2 document and physically merge them (or use a pdf insert for the pdf combined version).